systemctl what are these processes?
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.0-tty-ttyS0.device              loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.0/tty/ttyS0
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.1-tty-ttyS1.device              loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.1/tty/ttyS1
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.10-tty-ttyS10.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.10/tty/ttyS10
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.11-tty-ttyS11.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.11/tty/ttyS11
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.12-tty-ttyS12.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.12/tty/ttyS12
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.13-tty-ttyS13.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.13/tty/ttyS13
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.14-tty-ttyS14.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.14/tty/ttyS14
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.15-tty-ttyS15.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.15/tty/ttyS15
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.16-tty-ttyS16.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.16/tty/ttyS16
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.17-tty-ttyS17.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.17/tty/ttyS17
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.18-tty-ttyS18.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.18/tty/ttyS18
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.19-tty-ttyS19.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.19/tty/ttyS19
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.2-tty-ttyS2.device              loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.2/tty/ttyS2
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.20-tty-ttyS20.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.20/tty/ttyS20
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.21-tty-ttyS21.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.21/tty/ttyS21
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.22-tty-ttyS22.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.22/tty/ttyS22
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.23-tty-ttyS23.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.23/tty/ttyS23
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.24-tty-ttyS24.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.24/tty/ttyS24
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.25-tty-ttyS25.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.25/tty/ttyS25
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.26-tty-ttyS26.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.26/tty/ttyS26
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.27-tty-ttyS27.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.27/tty/ttyS27
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.28-tty-ttyS28.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.28/tty/ttyS28
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.29-tty-ttyS29.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.29/tty/ttyS29
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.3-tty-ttyS3.device              loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.3/tty/ttyS3
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.30-tty-ttyS30.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.30/tty/ttyS30
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.31-tty-ttyS31.device            loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.31/tty/ttyS31
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.4-tty-ttyS4.device              loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.4/tty/ttyS4
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.5-tty-ttyS5.device              loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.5/tty/ttyS5
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.6-tty-ttyS6.device              loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.6/tty/ttyS6
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.7-tty-ttyS7.device              loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.7/tty/ttyS7
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.8-tty-ttyS8.device              loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.8/tty/ttyS8
  sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.9-tty-ttyS9.device              loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/platform/serial8250/serial8250:0/serial8250:0.9/tty/ttyS9


I ran systemctl list-units and this popped up. I have no clue what they are and why I have so many. Can someone tell me what these are doing?

What makes you think those are processes?

systemctl list-units does not list processes, it lists units.
Units may or may not have a process associated with them.  If you pick a unit, you can run sytemctl status on that unit and get more details.
Picking the first item on your list, I get this:
$ systemctl status sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.0-tty-ttyS0.device
○ sys-devices-platform-serial8250-serial8250:0-serial8250:0.0-tty-ttyS0.device >
     Loaded: loaded
     Active: inactive (dead)

So this unit has no process associated with it.  Also, note that the unit name ends in .device.  If you read man systemd.device it says this is a "device unit configuration".  This type of unit will likely never have a process associated with it.
In your comment, you say you "don't have this many devices connected".  This doesn't mean much, because devices in unix may or may not correspond to physical devices, and even when they do correspond to physical devices, they may correspond to potential devices that are not actually connected, but are placeholders in case such a device is connected.
In this case, all the devices are named ttyS* which are hardware serial ports.  Modern PCs typically have one or two of these on the motherboard, although they may exist only as a socket on the motherboard with no actual connection outside the case unless you add that.  Linux always creates the devices for serial ports 0-31 even if the hardware doesn't exist for them.  This is just a feature of the serial device driver which statically allocates devices at kernel compile time rather than dynamically at runtime.  These do not take up significant resources.
If you want to know what processes are on your system, use the ps command.  But what processes are currently running still has very little to do with what is "on a fresh ubuntu".
If you want to know what services systemd knows about on your system, rather than list-units which lists everything systemd has detected, you might find list-unit-files more useful.  However, this lists both active and inactive units.  You can narrow this down further with systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled
If you want to know what packages are installed on your current ubuntu system, you can get a list with dpkg -l and you can get a description of a specific package with apt show packagename...
